# Integrating cron scheduler with meanjs

Tags: node.js, cron, mean-stack, meanjs

I am developing an app in mean stack. I have downloaded source code from  [mean.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean).
I would like to add  [node scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) that will run a periodic task every day . I don't get any idea of where can I put my code in meanjs application and how can I run the file? Simply I have starting trouble of where can I include my codes in the app

Answer (score 0):

After installing node-scheduler via npm, you can use a similar logic like the one used for multer or logger. Just create a `scheduler.js` file in `config/lib` in which you define the cron jobs you need and in the end of the file don't forget to export it (e.g., using `module.exports = scheduler;`).

Depending on how you have defined the file and what you want to achieve, you can then use it later within other MEAN.JS modules.